# Getting Paths of current opened file explorer windows from service

Tags: c#, filesystems, windows-services

I'm writing an application where I can save files in file explorer and they get saved in a mySQL database. I also have my own browser for the Database where I can browse for any file and they will get copied to the location it was initialy saved.

Now I want to create a **windows service** to update the files in the database and their location.
The file Creation, Moving, Editing,... works as desired but **I want to be able to load the files/folders in the path that is opened in Windows file explorer**.

So if I could get the paths or folder names from my open explorer windows I could dynamicaly load the files I need without having to load the full Database of files. And in doing so save space on my local disk.

This as an attempt of creating something that is searchable on a wide range of variables. And replacing the current Solidworks PDM for integrations in custom software for the company I work for.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need a shell extension for Explorer, not a service.  Services run in different user sessions than the interactively logged user.

Comment: @Nick do you maybe have a startingpoint for me. I'm writing a service because I need to do things outside of Explorer aswell. If there is no other way than the shell extension I will give it a go but most of the functions I needed are already programmed for a service.

Comment: @Oomke, I understand, but services are not for this.  You want to cross isolation boundaries within Windows (starting Vista).  I don't have a starting point.  Just pointing out that if you want to integrate / get data from Explorer, you need a Shell extension.  That's the right way of doing it.  All else would be a hack.